# In Energy-Dispersive X-ray Spectroscopy, do higher atomic elements ever generate just K lines without L or M lines?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrons

The heavier elements only show L or M lines. Is that because the critical ionisation energy is too high to get K lines in higher atomic numbers? Can you ever get just the K lines, or just the M lines or L lines?

Answer (score 1):

With a tuned X-ray source, e.g. from a [synchrotron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_light_source), it should, at least in theory, be possible to excite any specific line, or cause absorption at a specific wavelength, as in [X-ray absorption spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_absorption_spectroscopy).